# JavaScript error(s) occurred:

Tags: javascript, flash, error-handling

I just installed Partigen 2 ectention in Flash Pro CS6. I'm now getting this warning. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

The following JavaScript error(s) occurred:

```
ReferenceError: ebZipi386 is not defined
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

Comment: we need more informations to help you, code, context, etc...

Comment: Errors usually come with line numbers. That should get you started.
Also, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask